# Need to trim the domain from email and make value max 10 digits if it is more than 10 and ignore '.' if came in between

Tags: java, substring

To strip domain I am using this condition:

```
if (sender.indexOf('@') != -1 ) {
     sender = sender.substring(0, sender.indexOf("@"));
}
```

This will strip domain:
123456789@gmail.com -> 123456789

Now I need to add 1 more condition that it should take max 10 digit only with strip domain.

For example: stack.overflow@gmail.com -> should give stackoverf(max 10 digit)
In betwwen '.' we should ignore ?

How can we do this? Appreciate your responses.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: `"stackoverflow@gmail.com".substring(0, 10)`

Comment: @YCF_L that would only work if the name is guaranteed to be longer though
`sender = sender.substring(0, Math.min(sender.indexOf("@"), 10));`

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, changing to

```
if (sender.indexOf('@') != -1 ) {
     sender = sender.substring(0, Math.min(sender.indexOf("@"), 10));
}
```

will ensure the name will be cut after 10 characters

Comment: need your help in one more changes :   They want to ignore '.' if there in between  .

Comment: abc.xyz@gmail.com -> abcxyz (final result)                                                                                         sender.substring(0, Math.min(sender.indexOf("@"), 10)); -> here we need to add condition so that it can ignore '.' in between. Appreciate your response

Comment: For example: stack.overflow@gmail.com -> should give stackoverf(max 10 digit) In between '.' we should ignore ? How can we do this ?

Comment: Is this question visible as I can see it is in closed state ?

Comment: That would require several steps: `sender.substring(0, sender.indexOf("@").replace(".", "").substring(0, 10);`. I recommend taking a look at the documentation of the [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)-class, almost all string manipulation can be donw with the methods listed there.